# Find the distribution - coin is tossed three times

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A fair coin is tossed three times. Let $X$ be the number of heads that turn up on the first two tosses and $Y$ the number of heads that turn up on the third toss. Give the distribution of $X$, $Y$, $X + Y$, $X − Y$ and $XY$.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: $X=\{0,1,2\} Y=\{0,1\}$

Comment: $P(Y=1)=1/2, P(Y=0)=1/2,  P(X=0)=1/4, P(X=1)=1/2, P(X=2)=1/4$

Comment: you didn't told what you did or your problem with X+Y,X-Y

Comment: So is my answer ok ?

Comment: @ADG I think Karolina did show what she has done. She doesn´t know how to go further. And she made more effort than the most  of the questioner. here on math SE.

Comment: @KarolinaSz The probabilities for X+Y and X*Y are O.K.

Answer (score 2):

Is it good answer? 
$$X=\{0,1,2\},  Y=\{0,1\}$$
$$P(Y=1)=1/2, P(Y=0)=1/2,  P(X=0)=1/4, P(X=1)=1/2, P(X=2)=1/4$$
$$P(X+Y=0)=1/8, P(X+Y=1)=3/8, P(X+Y=2)=3/8, P(X+Y=3)=1/8$$
$$P(X-Y=-1)=1/8, P(X-Y=0)=3/8, P(X-Y=1)=3/8, P(X-Y=2)=1/8$$
$P(XY=0)=5/8, P(XY=1)=2/8, P(XY=2)=1/8$

Comment: The probabilities are ok. You can write them in a table, like $$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline X+Y & 0& 1     & 2 & 3  \\ \hline P(X+Y) & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{3}{8} & \frac{3}{8} &  \frac{1}{8} \\ \hline \end{array}$$

Comment: But isn´t $P(X*Y=1)=\frac{2}{8}$ ? There are two combination (1,0,1) and (0,1,1). And for $P(X*Y=0)$ I have $\frac{5}{8}$

Comment: you right, I corrrect it

Comment: Then it will be fine.

Comment: It looked like the OP asked for the distribution of $X-Y$, not $XY$.

Answer (score 0):

The distribution of $X+Y$ is a binomial distribution, as expected:

$$
q_0 = q_3 = 1/8 \\
q_1 = q_2 = 3/8
$$

where $q_i = P(X+Y = i)$.  This can be reasoned out as follows: You can obtain $0$ only if $X = Y = 0$, so the probability is $(1/4)(1/2) = 1/8$. You can obtain $3$ only if $X = 2, Y = 1$, so again the probability is $(1/4)(1/2) = 1/8$. Finally, you can obtain $1$ if $X = 1, Y = 0$, or *vice versa*, and you can obtain $2$ if $X = 2, Y = 0$ or $X = Y = 1$, and in either case the probability is $(1/4)(1/2)+(1/2)(1/2) = 3/8$.

Interestingly, the difference $X-Y$ has the same spread, only shifted down by one:

$$
r_{-1} = r_2 = 1/8 \\
r_0 = r_1 = 3/8
$$

where $r_i = P(X-Y = i)$. Can you see, by a similar consideration of the different possibilities, why that is?

ETA: Ahh, OK, for $XY$, again, a similar consideration of cases gives us

$$
p_0 = P(X = \mbox{anything}, Y = 0) + P(X = 0, Y = 1)
    = 1/2 + (1/4)(1/2) = 5/8 \\
p_1 = P(X = Y = 1) = (1/2)(1/2) = 1/4 \\
P_2 = P(X = 2, Y = 1) = (1/4)(1/2) = 1/8
$$

where $p_i = P(XY = i)$.